# Testing Rails module without loading ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, rails-activerecord

I'm working on a Rails app which I am testing with RSpec. After a lot of waiting for tests to finish, I've followed [Gary Bernhardt's advice](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/screencasts/catalog/fast-tests-with-and-without-rails) and [this informative post by Paul Annesley](http://paul.annesley.cc/2012/03/fast-rspec-slash-rails-tiered-spec-helper-dot-rb/) and setup a tiered spec_helper where I only load what parts of Rails I absolutely need, to keep test times down, and extract functionality into separate modules which I test in isolation.

This is working up to a point. The problem is that I have a module (extending `ActiveSupport::Concern`) with instance and class methods that build on ActiveRecord functionality, e.g. tying in to dynamic finders like `find_and_create_by_`. So far I've been able to just create a dummy class which includes the module and test on that, but now I'd like to move more logic from my ActiveRecord model into the module.

Concrete examples would be stuff like callbacks, validators, and method delegation, all of which are related by the fact that they relate to an API I'm accessing.

I'm stuck now though with two choices in my tests:

1. stub and/or mock every ActiveRecord method that I call in the module, which would keep the tests fast but potentially make the test code very complex, or
2. require activerecord in the test, make my dummy class inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` and just test the module as I would test any other rails model, which would be slower but keep the test code clean.

The latter option doesn't really appeal to me, since the whole reason I'm isolating the code in a module is that I want to separate it from Rails. I'm not looking for a black or white answer here, but would anyone have any advice or pointers to best practices on this situation? Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Are you using Factory Girl..!

Comment: No but I have in other projects. But that would not change the speed problem, you still need activerecord even if you're using factories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 seems tantalizing, but is fraught with peril IMHO. The scope of the mocking and stubbing that you would need to do is much like one of Rumsfeld's proverbial ["unknown unknowns"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_are_known_knowns). Would you eventually end up stubbing out all of ActiveRecord?

Even if you *could* make it it work, would it tolerate future changes in ActiveRecord? Would you have to update your mocks/stubs to keep up with new versions?

I would love to see a mocking library that can substitute ActiveModel/ActiveRecord for this very purpose. I'd say though that unless you have tolerance for spending what could end up being a lot of time building such a thing, that you're better off going with option 2.

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much the conclusion I had come to, but you put it in terms which make it easier for me to justify it to myself ;) I'll wait a bit more to see if other answers come in, otherwise I'll accept this one.

Comment: As a side note, I also had the thought that a gem for substituting essential components of ActiveModel/ActiveRecord for the purpose of testing would be pretty useful. I guess the work involved though makes it kind of unlikely to ever be built... [rspec/rails/mocks](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/rspec/rails/mocks.rb) has a very very little bit of what you'd need.

Answer (score 1):

The solution which works for me for speed up my testing process is by combining spork and guard, guard is actually to watch and run the tests but it will make your process speed.

I dont have a proper write up, but you could refer this gist on setting up the 
[spork with guard](https://gist.github.com/4304166)

and these are the resources I used

[guard](http://railscasts.com/episodes/264-guard?autoplay=true)

[spork](http://railscasts.com/episodes/285-spork?autoplay=true)

HTH

Comment: Yes I've used guard a bit and spork in the past. My hope was to avoid having to load activerecord at all, but I think that's pretty unrealistic, in which case other solutions such as these will have to do. Thanks!